# Why do some Pentecostal preachers claim that Lucifer was a worship leader?

Tags: biblical-basis, satan, worship, pentecostalism

Here in Brazil, there are some Pentecostal preachers who claim that Satan (Lucifer) was the "Minister of Praise in heaven" or the "ruler of the Celestial Choir".

According to a Pentecostal perspective, what the biblical basis for such an assertion?

Answer (score 14):

It is based on the understanding that some aspects of the Prophecy given by Ezekiel against the King of Tyre are more correctly directed at the demonic influence empowering that King identified to be Satan himself and the influence the KJV has had on the formation of Pentecostal doctrine.  Consider:

> 12 “Son of man, raise a lamentation over the king of Tyre, and say to him, Thus says the Lord God:
>   “You were the signet of perfection,
>       full of wisdom and perfect in beauty.
>   13 You were in Eden, the garden of God;
>       every precious stone was your covering,
>   sardius, topaz, and diamond,
>       beryl, onyx, and jasper,
>   sapphire, emerald, and carbuncle;
>       and crafted in gold were your settings
>       and your engravings.
>   On the day that you were created
>       they were prepared.
>   14 You were an anointed guardian cherub.
>       I placed you; you were on the holy mountain of God;
>       in the midst of the stones of fire you walked.
>   15 You were blameless in your ways
>       from the day you were created,
>       till unrighteousness was found in you.
>   16 In the abundance of your trade
>       you were filled with violence in your midst, and you sinned;
>   so I cast you as a profane thing from the mountain of God,
>       and I destroyed you, O guardian cherub,
>       from the midst of the stones of fire.
>   17 Your heart was proud because of your beauty;
>       you corrupted your wisdom for the sake of your splendor.
>   I cast you to the ground;
>       I exposed you before kings,
>       to feast their eyes on you.
>   18 By the multitude of your iniquities,
>       in the unrighteousness of your trade
>       you profaned your sanctuaries;
>   so I brought fire out from your midst;
>       it consumed you,
>   and I turned you to ashes on the earth
>       in the sight of all who saw you.
>   19 All who know you among the peoples
>       are appalled at you;
>   you have come to a dreadful end
>       and shall be no more forever.” - [Ezekiel 28:12-19 ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ez%2028%3A12-19&version=ESV)

It doesn't appear to be talking about just a man (despite that exact sense being given to the preceding verses). The particular sense of worship leader has come from translation of some of the obscure words in verse 13:

> 13 Thou hast been in Eden the garden of God; every precious stone was thy covering, the sardius, topaz, and the diamond, the beryl, the onyx, and the jasper, the sapphire, the emerald, and the carbuncle, and gold: **the workmanship of thy tabrets and of thy pipes was prepared in thee in the day that thou wast created**. - [Ezekiel 28:13 KJV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ez%2028%3A13&version=KJV) (emphasis added - cf. [other versions](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Ezekiel%2028:13))

This has been taken to mean that musical instruments have been incorporated into the very form of the 'guardian cherub' which seemed to have a special place on 'the holy mountain of God' hence the inference that the being referred to was the leader of worship in heaven. That it's identity is that of Lucifer is seen more from comparing this passage and in particular verse 17 with [Isaiah 14:12-14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=is%2014%3A12-14&version=KJV) (cf. also [this on-line article](http://www.gotquestions.org/King-of-Tyre.html)).

Comment: Lucifer is the worship leader, who in turn wanted to be worship as well.

Comment: Technically, wouldn't this verse just imply that the demon leading this king aside was once a "guardian cherub" involved with worship? Satan wasn't the only fallen angel, after all - this verse could easily be talking about one of his demonic minions.

Answer (score 0):

@nick0120000 if you go to Isaiah 14;14-29 explains that this is Lucifer specifically.  notice the same language used as Lucifer pridefully claims how he will ascend in heaven. He wants to be worshipped like God is worshipped.
So what is actually happening here in Ezekiel that was explained by bruised reed; is that the Lord Elohim so God and Jesus as it was in the garden are addressing the king of Tyre. But they are actually addressing the spirit backing the man.  Much the same way as Jesus called Peter Satan when they came to get him to crucify him and Peter drew his sword.  He wasn't literally calling Peter Satan.  But was rather addressing the spirit that was motivating him.  Peter must have been pretty special to have qualified for Satan and not just a demon to be using him.

By the way I do not think this is speaking of lucifer as a musician. Pipes are not only what water flows through or instruments like flutes etc.  There is also a decorative piping which is cord wrapped in fabric. The term isn't used much now but was some when I was a kid. And very few cushions have piping around them anymore.  But if you look up a high priest attire.And view pictures you will see the description fits well.
Plus there is the fact that in Deuteronomy 19:15 it speaks to let witness be established by 2 or 3. And God does so all throughout the bible.  So Ezekiel would be the only description of pipes being musical instrument built within a body.  However in Exodus 28:15-21 and Exodus 28:31 you can find very similar description of what Lucifer wore as a high priest garment. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).